# Django adding namespace to urls gives error Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, django-urls

Im trying to add this url to my app's urlpatterns (i.e. MyProject/MyApp/urls.py):

```
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login')
```

I have this snippet in one of my templates:

```
<a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
```

Normally, clicking on the link takes you to the login page successfully. However, when I try to add a namespace to my urls (app_name = my_namespace) and change the reverse to

```
<a href="{% url 'my_namespace:login' %}">Login</a>
```

it fails when I click on the link and I get the error

```
Reverse for 'login' not found. 'login' is not a valid view function or 
pattern name.
```

While all the other urls I reverse work with the namespace, it is just the login reverse that fails. Any idea why?

Edit:
MyProject/MyProject/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^clubinfo/', include('ClubInfo.urls')),
]
```

MyProject/MyApp/urls.py:

```
app_name = 'clubinfo'

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

A snippet of the template:

```
<a href="{% url 'clubinfo:index' %}">Home</a>
<a href="{% url 'clubinfo:login' %}">Login</a>
<a href="{% url 'clubinfo:register' %}">Register</a>
```

I can click on Home and Register, not login

Edit 2: auth_views is from this import:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
```

I think this may have something to do with why the program is raising an error.

Comment: Is `MyApp.urls` included in `MyProject.urls`?

Comment: Yes, every other url in the app works it seems its just the login that doesn't.

Comment: Okay. What's the URL in the browser address bar after you click the link?

Comment: Can you provide the whole `MyApp.urls` and `MyProject.urls` ?

Comment: @wencakisa I updated my post to include them

Comment: @OluwafemiSule the url is localhost8000/clubinfo/login/. My urls are edited into the post now.

Comment: Looks good to me. One more question. Where is `auth_views` imported from?

Comment: I have this import: from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem was in my login.html file which Django renders in its LoginView. I didn't use the namespace in one of my reverses in that file.

Answer (score 1):

in your project urls do this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^clubinfo/', include('ClubInfo.urls', namespace='clubinfo')),
]
```

now in clubinfo urls:
remove

```
app_name = 'clubinfo'
```

run de server again and try it should work that my way of doing

Answer (score 0):

I find that your

> app_name='clubinfo'

, but your urlpatterns is

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^clubinfo/', include('**ClubInfo**.urls')),
]
```